# Is there any way to convert an Adobe Pagemaker file to PDF?

Tags: pdf, conversion, word-processing, publishing

Is there any way to convert an Adobe Pagemaker file to PDF? Are there any plug ins or any third party softwares?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Pagemaker, but if it allows you to print you could always install a PDF printer like [CutePDF](http://cutepdf.com/).

Then simply select "print" in Pagemaker and select the PDF printer as the printer to print to and it should generate the printed output as a PDF file.